# Best way to make df.apply a function of index and column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have a single function be applied element-wise to a DataFrame. I would also like this function to take as arguments the current column and index.

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2), index=['a', 'b'], columns=['c', 'd'])

In [4]: df.head()
Out[4]: 
   c  d
a  0  1
b  2  3
```

Now I would want something like the following:

```
f = lambda x: foo(x, x.index_value, x.column_name)
df.apply(f)
```

In my specific use case, I have additional data structures/functions that are keyed on these values. Everything I have tried thus far loses at least one of the levels of information.

Here is an example `foo()`:

```
def foo(x, idx, col):
    # get data
    a = a_data.loc[idx, col]
    b = b_data.loc[idx, col]
    return a * x + b
```

For instance, I can extract column names or index names with `apply` and using `x.name`, but not both -- and `applymap` only passes scalar values to the function.

Here is the best attempt I've made so far. It's slow (and not very elegant) and I'd enjoy other suggestions:

```
In [4]: import itertools

In [5]: newdf = df.copy()

In [6]: for idx, col in itertools.product(df.index.values, df.columns):
   ...:     newdf.loc[idx, col] = f(df.loc[idx, col], idx, col)
   ...:
```

Comment: And neither `foo` nor `bar` can be vectorized?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, it's actually `foo(x, dx, col)`. I believe the function being applied can be vectorized. The part I'm unclear about is how to provide that function the element value, index value, and column value.

Comment: I added the answer I provided and deleted the answer post, FYI.

Comment: We would probably need to see what `foo` does in order to figure out a better answer than piRSquared's.

Comment: Ok, so there's not elegant way to do this then? By elegant, I mean using the vectorized operations of the `apply` and `applymap` family. This use case requires "brute-force" looping?

Comment: Either that or vectorize `foo` along one of the axes.

Comment: I'll add an example `foo` to clarify

Comment: In your case `df * a_data + b_data` should work. I guess the real function is more complicated?

Comment: correct, I was just trying to show a simple example. I care more about how to correctly utilize the pandas interface to be able to apply arbitrary (vectorizeable) functions that require column name and index value as arguments. sorry for not being clearer! should I edit the question further?

Comment: How about something like `df.apply(lambda col: a_data.loc[:, col.name] * col + b_data.loc[:, col.name]`?

Comment: This is close. I would probably have to retool some of my workflow to use this, because I have at least one function that has a signature like `foo` (i.e., it works on atomic data). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to use `at` method of the dataframe.  `loc` would work too but a bit slower.

```
foo = dict(a=1, b=2)
bar = dict(c=3, d=4)

for i in df.index:
    for j in df.columns:
        df.at[i, j] += foo[i] + bar[j]
```